# Trying to get a return URL when logging in from a profile page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

The problem I am having is a FormatException error An exception of type: 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). So the Guid is spot on and working when the return URL is commented out but when I include it for some reason the Guid is all zeros.
here is the code

```
        if (Request.QueryString["userId"] != null)
        {
            MasterPage masterpage = Page.Master;
            HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor)masterpage.FindControl("ancLogin");              


            Guid userId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["userId"]);
            User user = new User();
            user = user.GetById(userId);
            lblUserName.Text = user.UserName;
            imgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/" + user.ProfilePic;

            PostList posts = new PostList();
            posts = posts.GetByUserId(userId);
            CommentsList comments = new CommentsList();
            comments = comments.GetByUserId(userId);
            rptPost.DataSource = posts.List;
            rptPost.DataBind();
            rptComments.DataSource = comments.List;
            rptComments.DataBind();
            anchor.HRef = "/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=/Account/Profile.aspx?userId=" + userId;


            if (Session["User"] != null)
            {
                if (((User)Session["User"]).Id == userId)
                {

                    btnChangePicture.Enabled = true;
                    fuChangeProfileImage.Enabled = true;
                    fuChangeProfileImage.Visible = true;
                    btnChangePicture.Visible = true;
                }

            }
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
```

This is the line I am having trouble with when added to the code I get the format exception.
    anchor.HRef = "/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=/Account/Profile.aspx?userId=" + userId; 
Also this is like my second time ever asking a question here let me know if I formatted the code wrong or anything thanks!

Edit I fixed the problem I have some other concatenation going on in the login page and it was adding the userId twice. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong: the `userId` GUID is in the wrong format.

Comment: That is why it is a weird error because the format is correct, I use the same Guid to search through the database with my stored procedures, for instance this is a user profile and it is loading the comments and their post by that same userId. It changes to all zeros when I add the anchor href back into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid URL must be in this format:

```
baseURL?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3
```

In your case, replace

```
anchor.HRef = "/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=/Account/Profile.aspx?userId=" + userId;
```

with:

```
anchor.HRef = "/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=/Account/Profile.aspx&userId=" + userId;
```

Comment: I tried that also, but I then get a 404 error from the local server. Also I have a return URL that is exactly like this

Comment: in another aspx page. anchor.HRef = "/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=/ExpandedPost.aspx?postId=" + postId; <-- is the line, and it works perfectly with the ? instead of &. Sorry did not mean to make this two separate replies.

Comment: A 404 means that the page cannot be found. Mostly this means that the given URL does not point to a valid page.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible your guid contains some unwanted characters.
Convert guid in base64 before adding in query string and when convert back from base64 to string when you want to use.

You can use below code for conversion :-

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}

public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Guids can be safely added to querystrings. It's being done everywhere. No need to encode.